# How can I create a multiplication table as a matrix?

Tags: matlab

How can I create a multiplication table as a matrix in MATLAB?
I've been trying for a long time, but I've been unsuccessful, so far. I've issues with how to stack the different columns of the matrix together... Any help?

Comment: Show your code so we can help with it

Comment: Please attempt to **look** for questions that are related to your inquiry before posting a question to minimize clutter.  I found the above duplicate link by a simple Google search.

Comment: @rayryeng Sorry. I must admit I didn't think to look for a dupe before answering.

Comment: @Jubobs - haha no problem :).  I only knew about the duplicate because I've seen this question and its answer in the past.  I had the advantage in knowing about it.  In any case, I did upvote your answer as it's probably the most elegant solution I can think of - the outer product of two vectors.

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, an outer product came to mind directly, overriding any thought of looking for duplicates. Too tempting :)

Comment: @rayryeng Er... I should have known it's a duplicate, since I answered there too :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo - lol no problem my friend.  I still voted for your answer too as it's canonical.

Answer (score 5):

> I want to create a matrix of multiplication table.

You can do that by computing the outer product (a.k.a dyadic product) of the appropriate vector (called `x`, below) by itself:

```
>> x = [1 : 10].';    % for a multiplication table from 1*1 up to 10*10 (inclusive)

>> A = x * x.'        % n-by-1 times 1-by-n = n-by-n

A =

    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10
    2     4     6     8    10    12    14    16    18     20
    3     6     9    12    15    18    21    24    27     30
    4     8    12    16    20    24    28    32    36     40
    5    10    15    20    25    30    35    40    45     50
    6    12    18    24    30    36    42    48    54     60
    7    14    21    28    35    42    49    56    63     70
    8    16    24    32    40    48    56    64    72     80
    9    18    27    36    45    54    63    72    81     90
   10    20    30    40    50    60    70    80    90    100
```

Comment: Matrix multiplication! Of course!

Answer (score 4):

Here are some vectorized approaches. I suggest you read the linked documentation of each function to see how these approaches work.

Let `n` be the number you want the multiplication table of. Then you can do it:

1. Using [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

   ```
   t = bsxfun(@times, 1:n, (1:n).');
   ```
2. Using [`ndgrid`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html):

   ```
   ii = ndgrid(1:n);
   t = ii.*ii.';
   ```
3. Using [`cumsum`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) (since multiplication is repeated addition):

   ```
   t = cumsum(repmat(1:n, n, 1));
   ```